# Vim - yank from current cursor position till beginning of line

Tags: vim

in VIM, I understand that we can do a yank till the end of line using `y$` but if e.g. my text is `abcdefg` and my cursor is at **'g'** and I enter `y^` the line will be copy without the **g**. My idea is to copy the whole line without the line break, any similar action will do.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

0y$$ - copy the line without line break and move cursor back to the end

Comment: Or, more generally, ``0y$`]`` will move the cursor back to where it was.

Comment: I bet this is the only solution with least keystroke?

Answer (score 7):

Making it a visual selection and then yanking that includes the character under the cursor:

```
v0y
```

Comment: It might also require `set sel=inclusive`?

Comment: @cherhan, it does exactly what you want by default. Unless you changed explicitly the value of the `selection` option to something other than its default value, which seems silly.

Answer (score 3):

If all the characters are indeed together and conform to a "vim sentence", you could use visual selection for the `sentence` object. A `sentence` in this case would match `abcdefg` even if that is not starting at the beginning of a line and it will not include the line ending:

```
visy
```

If you want to include trailing whitespace you would use `a` instead of `i` (mnemonic for "inside"):

```
vasy
```

The only problem with this approach (which may be what you do not want) is that it will not include *leading* whitespace. So if you have something like:

```
    abcdefg
```

The selection will not include the leading chunk of whitespace, just `abcdefg`.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out yanking till end of line is a thing you'll find yourself doing quite often. As such, the following mapping is quite popular.

```
noremap Y y$
```

It's so popular, it's even listed under `:h Y`!

If you use this mapping, the answer to your question would be `0Y`

Comment: Omg yes, there is C and D and I dont understand why Y is not default bind too.

Answer (score 1):

```
0yg_
```

is another option.

But visual mode is better:

```
v0y
v^y
```